# How To Tell If a View Component Has Completely Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I am having an issue with view components in .NET Core 2.0. I need to be able to detect when a view component has finished loading in the parent view.

Once the view component has loaded, I need to set focus on a specific field that is part of the view component.

Currently, I am using JQuery `window.onload()`. However, in `window.onload()` the view component and any subsequent JavaScript has not fully render yet. 
Since it has not fully rendered the window.onload event can't find the specific field in the view component.

If I use `setTimeout` and set it's ms between 1000 and 3000, thus giving the view component time to finish loading, it works fine.
The problem with using `setTimeout` is that it isn't consistent. Depending on how long the page takes to load it may or may not set the focus on the specified field.

Here is the code jquery code.

```
var setSearchFocus = function () {
    if ($("#divSearch").is(":visible")) {
        $('#Diagnosis_Search').focus();
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(setSearchFocus, 1000);
}
```

divSearch is the div in the parent view where the view component is rendered.

Diagnosis_Search is the name of the field in the view component that needs to receive focus.

Appreciate any help with an alternate way to determine when a page has completely loaded or the ablity to detect when a view component has finished loading.

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it works

Comment: Are these "view" components in a child `iframe`?  It would help if you added markup to your question

Answer (score 0):

If you're up to using jQuery, you're better off using the document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(setSearchFocus, 1000);
});
```

OnLoad will fire before the entire document/page is ready. Using the `$(document).ready(...` approach will wait until your page is ready (in other words, when the DOM elements you want to interact with are present and rendered).

Comment: Thanks Pablo Recalde and Dortimer for the document.ready clarification. This helped some. However, I still need to determine in the document.ready whether or not the view component has finish loading. the final view component doesn't finish loading until after document.ready is fired.

Comment: "interact with are present and rendered" - `$(document).ready()` does fire when elements can be interacted with however, they may not necessarily be rendered yet.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the most common problems on web development. You're using `window.onload` which is **not** jquery. It is part of the Document Object Model (DOM) and as you have noticed it doesn't work as expected. This is why the guys @ jquery came up with document ready:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

or just

```
$(function() { console.log("ready!"); });
```

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

*UPDATE*: as per the comment on the other answer, I get that you've got to wait until an **iframe** loads your view component. Is that so? If it is, then try to listen to the iframe's `document` object, an iframe is like another whole webpage embedded on your site, so there's another `document` object for it. You can access this object from the parent by using

```
document.getElementById('divSearch').contentWindow.document
```

you see a document that contains other document, which is actually what we're doing with the iframe. Beware this line isn't going to work if the document you're loading on the iframe is not on the same origin (not part or the same web or in the same TLD), but as you told us that this is a viewComponent this isn't the case probably.

To sum up, try with `$(iframe#youriframeid).ready(function() { console.log("ready!"); })` instead.

Comment: "or even" - those really are equivalent and on the same event i.e. would both fire at the same given time since they do the same thing as you have it written. (different forms of the same thing), the latter is the recommended form.

Comment: I'm sorry English is not my native language, I was trying to say that "or even in a simpler syntax:".

Comment: I've should choose "or just" instead @MarkSchultheiss ?

Comment: Note `$(iframe#youriframeid).ready(function(){});` does NOT fire on that child DOM ready but on the parent DOM ready event and is the same as `$(function(){});`

Comment: of course it does not fire on the child I've never said that. I'm always speaking of knowing when the IFRAME is loaded from the PARENT. About the event that get fired, I don't think so. please provide some proof. You can find similar answers on this matter on this site. And I think I did something similar on MVC4 with ViewComponents

Comment: Clarity for this is in the documentation https://api.jquery.com/ready/ scroll down to "jQuery offers several ways to attach a function that will run when the DOM is ready."

Comment: It is not the same.